# How to say “You are killing me” in French?

Tags: traduction, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Is there an idiomatic expression for “you are killing me” in French? 
or anything that will denote the meaning, except “tu me tues”.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context; for instance, what is that person actually saying or doing which makes you say that? Thanks!

Comment: "Tu me tues" me semble la traduction la plus proche si on y adjoint un adjectif genre *Sérieux, tu me tues*. L'enlever des propositions possibles rend l'exercice vraiment difficile.

Answer (score 5):

One would say in French :

- *Tu me tues*, as you said (which, depending on the context, would be the most accurate translation) ;
- *T'es pas croyable*/*T'es incroyable*, which translates literally into *You're incredible* ;
- *Tu me fais rêver* or *Tu m'envoies du rêve*, those would be the most accurate translations of *you're killing me* regardless of the context ;
- *Je n'en peux plus de toi* (or *J'en peux plus de toi*, note that the "*ne*" part has been removed since it is usually spoken, not written), which roughly translates into this expression.

Those expressions aren't used in written French at all. They are mostly used with people you know and they shouldn't be used with your boss. He might be killing you afterwards. Not in the funny way.

Comment: Je n'en peux plus fits the meaning perfectly ! Thank you

Comment: -1 "J'en peux plus de toi" n'est absolument pas une traduction possible. "Tu me fais rêver" là je suis perplexe ; est ce un régionalisme ? Ça a juste pratiquement rien à voir.

Comment: Les 2 sont utilisés couramment à l'oral, bien que plutôt chez les jeunes en fait. Aucun des deux n'est particulier à une région. "J'en peux plus de toi" a l'air péjoratif dans son sens premier mais il est de plus en plus utilisé dans ce sens-là (dans le sens où la personne qui dit ça ne peut/pourrait plus rire, pour des raisons physiques) des histoires de la personne en face. "Tu me fais rêver" je l'ai entendu un peu partout, après l'avoir vu la 1e fois sur Internet.

Comment: @PaulPicard _Tu me fais rêver_ bien c'est tout à fait régulier; mais traduire "you're killing me" ainsi... pourquoi? On voudrait dire que faire rêver c'est _être diverti_ ?? Voir [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/killing) par exemple avec plusieurs indices sur différents trucs. Aussi [Merriam learner](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/kill). Je ne suis pas convaincu. Merci!

Comment: C'est dans le sens où l'histoire est divertissante,drôle, mais aussi "incroyable", inattendu. Un exemple d'utilisation (un peu étrange, certes, mais le premier qui me passe par la tête) serait en réponse à "J'ai mis du sucre sur mes frites en pensant que c'était du sel".

Comment: +1 pour "j'en peux plus de toi" de nos jours généralement abrégé "jpp" quand écrit sur internet ou par sms.

Answer (score 3):

Un petit régionalisme de mon enfance pour la route ; à Bordeaux, on disait à l'époque :

> Mon sang par terre !

Comment: J’ai entendu l'expression utilisée à propos de personnes très proches, en particulier des enfants. J'entendais cela ainsi : toi à qui je tiens comme à mon propre sang, ton comportement et ta situation sont pour moi ressentis comme une mutilation, comme un gaspillage de mon propre sang (d'où l'usage pour des enfants). Cela traduit à mon sens une forme d'attachement extrême, envahissant, peut-être un peu méditerranéen ou “mère juive”.

Comment: Merci! C'est fort intéressant; au final ça me fait penser à _jeter par terre_ (je comprends un truc comme _ça me jette à terre_) c'est-à-dire _abattre/détruire_ ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/terre)) avec au surplus la composante héréditaire... une idée d'exaspération très particulière(mon interprétation). Et donc je peux comprendre pourquoi on peut en faire une réponse. Le contexte de la question est insuffisant. Merci!

Answer (score 2):

- Si vous voulez dire "you are making me die of laughter", au Quebec on pourrait dire "Tu me fais cramper";
- Si vous voulez dire "you are destroying me physically, change what you're doing", on pourrait dire  "Je ne suis plus capable" ou "J'suis plus/pu capable";
- Mais on voit plutôt souvent le sens que relate [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You%27re%20killing%20me%20smalls) "tu bousilles mes chances, détruit mon progrès, tu me fais désespérer" (qui est tiré d'un film) et qui serait possiblement remplacé par un juron...

Comment: _Tu me fais cramper à mort_ peut-être aussi ? Plus capable... d'endurer ce que tu me fais subir; _j'en ai assez_ ? Dans le dernier cas, "_tu me fais chier_" marcherait aussi bien au Québec qu'[ailleurs](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chier)!

Comment: +1 Avec "cramper" j'ai vu aussi "... fais cramper au boutte" et "... fais cramper comme un cheval." Pour les contextes moins drole peut-etre on pourrait se servir de ce "boutte" pour dire "tu me fais arriver/chier (tu m'envoies?) au boutte du boutte [avec tes conneries/insultes/etc]." @Amphiteóth

Comment: Pas "tu m'envoyes"; ça impliquerait que l'autre m'a insulté... Oui, le "_bout' du bout'_", mais surtout avec un verbe d'état, donc "je suis au bout du bout(du [rouleau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouleau) ?), je suis (rendu)/tu me rends à bout(de [nerfs](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nerf) sans doute)". Me faire cramper "au boutte", oui, mais avec "au boutte du boutte", jamais entendu; ni cheval d'ailleurs. Merci!

Answer (score 2):

in the sense of "what you do is too much for me", you can also use :

> Tu m'exaspères

which is more formal

Answer (score 0):

One can also say “J'en ai marre de toi”, which is like to say “I can't bear you anymore”.

Answer (score 0):

"Tu me tues"...

Si on est énervé, ça voudra dire qu'on est vraiment à bout de la personne à qui on s'adresse, qu'on en a vraiment marre d'elle.

Si on est entre amis et qu'il y en a un qui nous fait beaucoup rire, on peut dire "Ha ha ha tu me tues" (en riant très fort à en avoir mal au ventre en général). :)

En Belgique en tout cas, ça s'entend, surtout chez les jeunes quand ils se marrent entre eux.

Par contre, je déconseille de le dire à une personne que l'on ne connait pas ou très peu (ou alors, il faut vraiment un super feeling avec la personne.